# How to use data.table fifelse with vectors in the arguments?

Tags: r, vector, conditional-statements, data.table, na

Say I have this data.frame

```
DF <- data.frame(one=c(1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA), two=c(NA,1,NA, NA, NA,1), 
         three=c(NA,NA, 1, NA, 1,NA))

one    two  three         output
  1     NA    NA             one
 NA      1    NA             two
 NA     NA     1           three
  1     NA    NA             one  
 NA     NA     1           three
 NA      1    NA             two
```

The columns are mutually exclusive.
I need to generate the output

```
output=c("one","two","three","one","three", "two")
```

I've tried to to it with data.table fifelse but it

```
with(DF,fifelse(one==1, "one", fifelse(two==1,"two", "three", na="three"), 
   na=fifelse(two==1,"two", "three", na="three")))

Error in fifelse(one == 1, "one", fifelse(two == 1, "two", "three", na = "three"),  : 
  Length of 'na' is 6 but must be 1
```

It seems it doesn't accept a vector on the arguments.

dplyr's if_else works well here.

```
with(DF,if_else(one==1, "one", if_else(two==1,"two", "three", missing="three"), 
   missing=if_else(two==1,"two", "three", missing="three")))
```

How can I get the same output with data.table?

Any other simple alternative.
With R base I could use

```
apply(DF,1, function(x) which(!is.na(x)))
```

and later replace that numbers with characters.

Answer (score 3):

`fifelse` isn't the best tool for this, I suggest `fcase` is easier:

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(DF)[, fcase(one == 1, "one", two == 1, "two", three == 1, "three")]
# [1] "one"   "two"   "three" "one"   "three" "two"
```

## dplyr

The dplyr analog is `case_when`:

```r
library(dplyr)
with(DF, case_when(one == 1 ~ "one", two == 1 ~ "two", three == 1 ~ "three"))
# [1] "one"   "two"   "three" "one"   "three" "two"
```

## base R

Both the `data.table` and `dplyr` implementations presume knowing the column names a priori. A base-R method that is agnostic to that:

```r
colnames(DF)[apply(DF, 1, which.max)]
# [1] "one"   "two"   "three" "one"   "three" "two"
```

(Incidentally, `which.max` can also be `which.min` here, really we're just looking for a non-`NA` value.)

In this case, if you have other columns that should not be considered, you will need to subset the `DF` within `apply(DF, ...)` so that it only looks at the desired columns.

Comment: I like `m <- t(as.matrix(DF)); rownames(which(m == 1 & !is.na(m), arr.ind = TRUE))` although it wouldn't scale well.

Answer (score 3):

Another data.table alterntive:

```
for (col in names(DF)) set(DF, which(DF[[col]] == 1), j = "output", value = col)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one non-NA value each row, you can try `max.col`

```
> names(DF)[max.col(!is.na(DF))]
[1] "one"   "two"   "three" "one"   "three" "two"
```

or `col` + `na.omit` (but this might be slow if you are pursuing the speed)

```
> names(DF)[na.omit(c(t(col(DF) * DF)))]
[1] "one"   "two"   "three" "one"   "three" "two"
```

## Benchmarking

```
microbenchmark(
    f1 = names(DF)[max.col(!is.na(DF))],
    f2 = names(DF)[na.omit(c(t(col(DF) * DF)))]
)
```

gives

```
Unit: microseconds
 expr   min     lq    mean median    uq    max neval
   f1  28.5  51.45  92.343  64.40  91.8 1532.5   100
   f2 300.7 527.65 634.755 595.35 691.5 2405.4   100
```